# How to unwrap a shared global object with mut reference - while at the same time have it thread safe

Tags: rust

I have a global object:
`static ms: MainStruct = MainStruct::new();`

which I am consuming in a multithreaded (not in the sample code provided here) logic like this:

```
// consumers
pub struct Consumer {
    s_: String
}

impl Consumer {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        Consumer {
            s_: s,
        }
    } 
    
    fn Process(&self) -> bool {
        println!("consumer {} processing", self.s_);
        ms.store_data();
        ms.read_data();
        true
    }
}

fn main() {
    let con = Consumer::new(String::from("simple consumer"));
    con.Process();
}
```

What I am trying to do is object `ms` of type `MainStruct` is going to be consumed in multiple threads. While you may notice that `ms` is not wrapped in any synchronizing constructs - this is because `ms` object (`MainStruct`) is just a wrapper to another object `ParentStruct` composed inside with all the necessary constructs, to have the following properties:

1. Thread safe
2. Can be unwrapped with reference
3. Should be implemented in generically (though here I have only used for `DummyData`)

While hierarchy of these objects may not look necessary in this example, but in the actual code, where by having this design is making some of my interfaces simpler.

Now when I am trying to build this program I am running into compile time errors, as you may see in the sample program.

I have tried many things so far, but I could not crack the constraints that Rust compiler wants me to satisfy.

Here is the full program:

```
use std::{any::Any, sync::{Mutex, Arc}};

// consumable

pub struct DummyData {
    a_: u32,
    b_: String,
}

impl DummyData {
    fn new(a: u32, b: String) -> Self {
        DummyData {
            a_: a,
            b_: b,
        }
    }
    
    fn write(&mut self, a: u32, b: String) -> bool {
        self.a_ = a;
        self.b_ = b;
        true
    }
    
    fn read(&self) -> &'static Self {
        &self
    }
}

// producers
pub trait DataReader {
    fn store_data(&self) -> bool;
    fn read_data(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct ParentStruct {
    obj_inst_: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Any>>>
}

impl ParentStruct {
    pub fn new(inst: Box<dyn Any>) -> Self {
        ParentStruct {
            obj_inst_: Arc::new(Mutex::new(inst))
        }
    }
    
    pub fn ref_instance(&self) -> &'static Mutex<Box<dyn Any + '_>> {
        &self.obj_inst_
    }
}

unsafe impl Sync for ParentStruct {}

pub struct MainStruct {
    p_: ParentStruct
}

impl MainStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MainStruct {
            p_: ParentStruct::new(Box::new(DummyData::new(59, String::from("Apple"))))
        }
    }
}

impl DataReader for MainStruct {
    fn store_data(&self) -> bool {
        let p = self.p_.ref_instance();
        let unlock_p = p.lock().unwrap();
        match (*unlock_p).downcast::<DummyData>() {
            Ok(c) => {
                // let cd = Box::into_inner (c);
                let ret = (*c).write(45, String::from("hello"));
                println!("write: {}", ret);
                return true;
            },
            _ => {
                return false;
            }
            Err(_) => todo!(),
        }
    }
    
    fn read_data(&self) -> bool {
        let p = self.p_.ref_instance();
        let unlock_p = p.lock().unwrap();
        match (*unlock_p).downcast::<DummyData>() {
            Ok(c) => {
                let ret = c.read();
                print!("read: {} {}", ret.a_, ret.b_);
                return true;
            },
            _ => {
                return false;
            }
            Err(_) => return false,
        }
    }
}

static ms: MainStruct = MainStruct::new();

// consumers

pub struct Consumer {
    s_: String
}

impl Consumer {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        Consumer {
            s_: s,
        }
    } 
    
    fn Process(&self) -> bool {
        println!("consumer {} processing", self.s_);
        ms.store_data();
        ms.read_data();
        true
    }
}

fn main() {
    let con = Consumer::new(String::from("simple consumer"));
    con.Process();
}
```

Also same in playground Link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b7eb94dd6e30f9c302b66a7a772c9e1

I am broadly struggling with lifetime of some of the object-ref I am trying to access by reference and not the object around.

Here is what I am getting in building this:

```
`   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:24:9
   |
23 |     fn read(&self) -> &'static Self {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
24 |         &self
   |         ^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:78:13
   |
75 |             _ => {
   |             - matches any value
...
78 |             Err(_) => todo!(),
   |             ^^^^^^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default

error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src/main.rs:66:17
   |
65 |     fn store_data(&self) -> bool {
   |                   -----
   |                   |
   |                   `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                   let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
66 |         let p = self.p_.ref_instance();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 `self` escapes the method body here
   |                 argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `MutexGuard<'_, Box<dyn Any>>`
    --> src/main.rs:68:15
     |
68   |         match (*unlock_p).downcast::<DummyData>() {
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ ----------------------- value moved due to this method call
     |               |
     |               move occurs because value has type `Box<dyn Any>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
     |
note: `Box::<(dyn Any + 'static), A>::downcast` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
    --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1736:29
     |
1736 |     pub fn downcast<T: Any>(self) -> Result<Box<T, A>, Self> {
     |                             ^^^^

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*c` as mutable, as `c` is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:71:27
   |
71 |                 let ret = (*c).write(45, String::from("hello"));
   |                           ^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
help: consider changing this to be mutable
   |
69 |             Ok(mut c) => {
   |                +++

warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:94:13
   |
91 |             _ => {
   |             - matches any value
...
94 |             Err(_) => return false,
   |             ^^^^^^ unreachable pattern

error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
  --> src/main.rs:83:17
   |
82 |     fn read_data(&self) -> bool {
   |                  -----
   |                  |
   |                  `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
83 |         let p = self.p_.ref_instance();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 `self` escapes the method body here
   |                 argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `MutexGuard<'_, Box<dyn Any>>`
    --> src/main.rs:85:15
     |
85   |         match (*unlock_p).downcast::<DummyData>() {
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ ----------------------- value moved due to this method call
     |               |
     |               move occurs because value has type `Box<dyn Any>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
     |
note: `Box::<(dyn Any + 'static), A>::downcast` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
    --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1736:29
     |
1736 |     pub fn downcast<T: Any>(self) -> Result<Box<T, A>, Self> {
     |                             ^^^^

error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `MainStruct::new` in statics
  --> src/main.rs:99:25
   |
99 | static ms: MainStruct = MainStruct::new();
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
   = note: consider wrapping this expression in `Lazy::new(|| ...)` from the `once_cell` crate: https://crates.io/crates/once_cell

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0015, E0507, E0521, E0596.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0015`.
warning: `playground` (bin "playground") generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 7 previous errors; 2 warnings emitted`
```

Comment: This can be broken up into many smaller problems: the "unreachable pattern" warnings should be self evident, the "move out of MutexGuard" error can be addressed by using the non-consuming `downcast_ref` or `downcast_mut` methods instead, and the "cannot call non-const MainStruct::new" can be fixed by using lazy initialization (see answer [here](/a/27826181) for options).

Comment: Your `unsafe impl Sync` is unsound. And generally you should not write `unsafe impl`s yourself. Instead you should use `Box<dyn Any + Send>`.